# Cakephp webpage title from db table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I would like to be able from my panel admin  to change index.ctp title whenever i wanna to. Thats why i created table "websites" widh columns "id" and "par", model for that table "Website" and controller "WebsitesController". But i would like to write all of it in my main Website controller named "InfosController",

i Would like to connect to table and print column "par"'s value  as a webpage title. But i managed error "An Internal Error Has Occurred."
I think the problem is in controller, but i can't figure it out.

InfosController.php

```
public function admin_index()
{

    $this->set('title_for_layout',  $this->title());
    $this->Info->recursive = 1;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 2,
        'order'=>array('id'=>'desc')
    );
    $informer = $this->paginate('Info');
    $this->set('inform', $informer);
}

public function title()
{
    $this->loadModel('Website');
    $dane = $this->Website->findById(1);
    $title = $dane['Website']['par'];
    return $title;
}
```

in admin_index.ctp i have

```
...
 <title><?php echo $title_for_layout ?></title>
...
```

everything is getting worse after loading model, any guesses ?

EDIT:

ok, I managed it. Somehow my controller want to have access to column from my table that doesn't exist. so i had to craete column "info_id" with null values in my websites table, and everythings working.. Pretty strange, huh ?

Comment: *...everything is getting worse after loading model.* also makes me wonder why but I have no guesses.

Comment: ok, I managed it. Somehow my controller want to have access to column from my table that doesn't exist. so i had to craete column "info_id" with null values in my websites table, and everythings working.. Pretty strange, huh ?

Answer (score 0):

try to debug $dane inside the title() method ... and also handle exceptions while doing a findby , in case the website that u're looking for is not found or smth .

try also to avoid loading models for uncessery actions , and it will be better if you store the website infos inside a Session .